# HTML/PHP - default input value

Tags: php, forms, input, default-value

I have a post php form and a set of inputs:

1. Your Name
2. Your Last Name
3. My Name

Every input looks the same, only the names change:

```
<input type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php echo get_option('your_name'); ?>" />
```

How to set default values when value= is not available?

[edit]

Ok, so, normally I'd do something like:

```
<input type="text" name="your_name" value="Mike" />
```

But in this case I have a PHP script that grabs inputs data and displays it using `value="<?php echo get_option('your_name'); ?>"` . So I have no idea how to force my form to display "Mike" in my input.

Comment: I don't understand under what circumstances `value=` would **not** be available. Can you clarify *why* it might not be available?

Comment: @David Thomas, updated the question.

Comment: Please also remember to escape special characters!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php

Comment: @Wordpressor You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) to do it more simply, check my answer, please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check the return of get_option first, and substitute something if a default is not available

```
<?php
    $default = get_option('your_name');
    if( $default == "")
    {
        $default = <whatever your default value is>;
    }
?>
<input type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php echo $default; ?>" />
```

Change get_option to return an empty string (or something else) if the default is not available.

Comment: You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) to do it more simply

Answer (score 2):

you can change the `get_option()` function to be something like

```
function get_option($name) {
   $defaults = array(
      'fist_name' => 'Mike',
      'fist_name' => 'Wordpressor',
      'my_name' => 'Dunno'
   );
   // get the value from the $defaults array
   $val = $defaults[$name];

   // but if the same value has already been posted - replace the default one
   if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
      $val = $_POST[$name];
   }
   return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is How I solved this issue in my problem which I believe is similar, when $_POST is read the value is populated from the $_POST value else sets a default of Mike

```
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; else echo "Mike"?>" >
```

Hope this helps someone oneday

Comment: to avoid XSS attacks, replace `echo $_POST['name']` above with `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a switch statement and have default to be whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Since `value` is the default, just add a condition around your `get_option`-function, maybe something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php $var = get_option('your_name'); if ($var == '') $var = 'your_default'; echo $var; ?>" />
```

Comment: it's not the best practice to write all the logic inside the html :)

Comment: Very true, but I was just demonstrating the means to get there. A structured detachment from php code and HTML should be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Teneff but I would break it out.

In the index.php I would have the following at the top of the doc

```
<?
$defaultText = include 'default_text.php';  
?>
```

where your forms are it would be:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="names"><? echo $defaultText; ?> </input> 
</form>
```

then I would have a seperate file on the root level called "default_text.php."

```
<?
$Name = <<<EOD Name EOD;
return $Name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php echo empty(get_option('your_name')) ? "TheDefaultValue" : get_option('your_name'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
$default = ValueResolver::resolve(get_option('your_name'), '<whatever your default value is>');
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a ternary operator. its pretty easy try this

```
$default = 'Mike';

$your_name = get_option('your_name');

$condition = !empty($your_name) ? $your_name : $default;

<input type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php echo $condition; ?>" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Set some variable at start with the post variables.

like

```
$name_val = "";
if(isset($_POST["your_name"])
{
    $name_val = $_POST["your_name"];
}

<input type="text" name="your_name" value="<?= $name_val?>">
```

Comment: There is a huge XSS hole in that.

Comment: And, not to be ridiculously picky, an un-terminated line of php in the `value` attribute.

Comment: @David Thomas, what do you mean by un-terminated line?

Comment: @Ummar there's no terminating `;` following the `$name_val`. Strictly speaking, I don't think there *has* to be, but...it just niggles me when it's not there. (Although I haven't down-voted the answer.)

Comment: Please stop using short open tags. They might be disabled in some configurations and PHP might stop supporting it in the future.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, `short_open_tag` is opened by default in php configuration... and according to php docs it's not deprecated. [PHP docs] (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: But there are many server configurations that have it disabled. Moreover, only `<?` might confuse programs that also work with other languages, like XML.

Comment: @Quentin As someone looking at PHP for the very first time, could you please elaborate on your comment about "a huge XSS hole" in the provided answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin OK, thanks.  So, the posted code is problematic because the variable is being evaluated, so if it contains code, it will run.  IIU, printing the variable would be OK.  Thanks.

Comment: @JodyHagins — No. Printing the variable sends it to the browser where it will be evaluated as HTML (which can embed JS).