# How can I properly escape HTML form input default values in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, xss

Given the following two HTML/PHP snippets:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" />
```

and

```
<textarea name="content"><?php echo $_POST['content']; ?></textarea>
```

what character encoding do I need to use for the echoed `$_POST` variables? Can I use any built-in PHP functions?

Please assume that the `$_POST` values have not been encoded at all yet. No magic quotes - no nothing.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname'])` and `htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'])`.

Always escape strings with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before showing them to the user.

Comment: However, htmlspecialchars() won't help you with `value='single quotes'` This is what happens: `value='We're not using this in our &quot;code&quot;...'` All you see is `We`

Comment: so, don't use single quotes in values. or use ENT_QUOTES modifier. not a big deal

Comment: Note: It is important to use double quotes for the value attribute in `<input>` tags.

Comment: Unless you specify `ENT_QUOTES` as the second `htmlspecialchars()` argument, single quotes will not be escaped. Therefore any single quotes present in your `$_POST` value will break out of the `<input>` field.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Presumably post data is coming from the user, so "don't use single quotes in values" is not terribly helpful advice. Using `ENT_QUOTES` is the correct solution, but remembering to do so could be a "big deal".

Comment: Note: Don't be tempted to use htmlentities(). That breaks UTF-8 characters. As rid said, use htmlspecialchars().

Comment: if you don't use `ENT_QUOTES` parameter then single quotes are not escaped. This is not a problem if in the input tag you define the value parameter as `value="double quotes"`. The double quotes are escaped in the user provided string and the part with `value="...` is provided by the server.

Comment: @Brainware Even now that htmlentities() defaults to UTF-8?

Comment: that's the output escaping. User wanted to know input escaping.

Answer (score 4):

[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) would work in both cases. Have a look at the different flag options to avoid quotation marks being a problem in the `input` case.

Answer (score 1):

Given it is kinda long I would put it in a function

```
<?PHP
function encodeValue ($s) {
    return htmlentities($s, ENT_COMPAT|ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1', true); 
}
?>
```

This has **ENT_QUOTES** to make sure single and double quotes are encoded, but it will also **encode special characters** (Like in José) instead of inserting an empty string.

Then you can do:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= encodeValue($_POST['firstname']) ?>" />
```

and

```
<textarea name="content"><?= encodeValue($_POST['content']) ?></textarea>
```

Comment: `ENT_QUOTES` only would be enough to escape both double and single.

Comment: Not clear why this answer specifies `ISO-8859-1` rather than the more commonly used today, default, value `UTF-8`. If in doubt, start with simpler `return htmlentities($s, ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, why IOS-8859-1 vs UTF-8 because that is what worked and I never tested UTF-8. Welcome some investigation there. Just using ENT_QUOTES does not work for characters with accents and will screw up names.