# How do I escape quotes for HTML input (using PHP)?

Tags: php, regex, security, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How can I properly escape HTML form input default values in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-can-i-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

If I use a preset HTML input, for example:

```
$lmao=$_POST['lmao'];

echo <<<EOD
<input value="{$lmao}" name="lmao" type="text">
EOD;
```

If a **"** character gets into the variable, it will result in poo, and also a data loss on re-submission.

I could, of course:

```
preg_replace('/"/', '', $lmao);
```

But what if I wanted to keep that quote?

Comment: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Re *"result in poo"*: Can you be more specific (unless it is literal)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All user-inputted data that is being output within HTML attributes should be run through htmlspecialchars. This encodes quotes and other characters:

```
echo '<input value="'.htmlspecialchars($lmao).'" name="lmao" type="text">';
```

Comment: Don't forget you need to take the charset and the HTML version into account when using htmlspecialchars!  `htmlspecialchars ($lmao, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')`