# Disable injection

Tags: php, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly escape html form input default values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

I am currently using:

```
if (isset($_GET['b']))
{
  $bb = $_GET['b'];
  echo 'found';
}
else
{
  $bb = 'white';
  echo 'notfound';
}
```

and

```
<body bgcolor="<?php echo $bb; ?>">
```

to allow the users to set the color of the page, what would be the safest method to avoid injection?

Comment: Long sleeved shirts could be good. Or a suit of armour. However I suspect you are not talking about those sorts of injections - care to expand on what you really mean?

Comment: Try [htmlspecialchars($bb)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: People would be able to inject javascript files to steal data from the text fields, the whole point of the page is so that users can use an iframe on their site and set the background accordingly

Comment: @NanashiDri I'm glad someone said it.You can 'avoid' anything you want but I can always open my inspector and change anything on the client side. You cannot control this.

Comment: @Nanashi if the $bb is `red"><script>alert("Injected!")</script><br class="x` it should result in `<body bgcolor="red"><script>alert("Injected!")</script><br class="x">`

Comment: @user1841964 - The Betty Ford clinic - but why should somebody want to steal their own input fields. Amnesia perhaps.

Comment: @rlemon partly right. But (not in this case, of course) if one's clever enough, for example by adding a forged chat post, it is possible to alter the page content in malicious ways too... Like using a bit of JS to read the contents of all the input elements and redirect their content to a 3rd party site using AJAX... (I have to emphasize, not in this case, as here nothing gets stored - or at least it seems)

Comment: You don't steal the input fields, you steal the authority of the site that allows XSS as a third party.

Comment: He could also use a color picker in addition to input sanitation.

Comment: @ppeterka, so you're stating that it would be different doing that and using the browser console? Of course, assuming nothing is saved.

Comment: @EdHeal since the url works as a referral system, it allows one to embed the iframe containing the url into their page and receive funds for every user registered, having flaws such as this would sabotage the safety of the users that register from the iframe. Neither drug or alcohol abuse is funny and it is completely off topic.

Comment: @user1841964 - Javascript and the sandbox model. As to replying on Javascript for security is silly. If so concerned and one supposes this system is open to all, beef up security (firewalls etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are expecting a color, you could use a regex for hexadecimal colors:

```
^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$
```

and the list of the 17 standard colors: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, grey, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow:

```
$standards = array(
    'aqua',
    'black',
    'blue',
    'fuchsia',
    'gray',
    'grey',
    'green',
    'lime',
    'maroon',
    'navy',
    'olive',
    'purple',
    'red',
    'silver',
    'teal',
    'white',
    'yellow'
);

if (in_array($bb, $standards) or preg_match('/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/', $bb)) {
    // valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always validate that `$bb` only consists of `a-zA-Z0-9`, which would make it work with one-word color names (such as `white`, `black`, `grey`) as well as hexadecimal color codes (without the leading `#` that is). :)

Comment: The user could use `#zzzzzz`. We don't want that, right?

Comment: No, obviously he'd have to check that too if he want's to ensure ONLY valid hexcodes. However, there is no harm in using `#zzzzzz`, and if the user really wants it... well, they'll have it, just that it doesn't really exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to escape special chars and the quotes:

```
<body bgcolor="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($bb, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

These kind of regexes could validate what you need. You can [check it here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wF6qEL).

```
// match ffffff & fff
if (!preg_match('/^([a-fA-F0-9]{3}|[a-fA-F0-9]{6})$/i', $bb, $matches_bb2)) {
  $color = $bb;
}

// check other color
preg_match('/[\w]+/i', $bb, $matches_bb);

// not a valid string (means no space, no accent, etc ..)
if (isset($matches_bb[0]) && $matches_bb[0] != $bb) {
  $bb = 'white';
}
```