# Any solve there to not execute </textarea> tag(which contained $values)?

Tags: php, html, tags, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly escape html form input default values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

I am facing problem on facing `</textarea>` element.
I am working on whole php file edit. If the php file has `</textarea>` tag it closes the files codes.
E.g.

```
$data=file_get_contents($file);
..
'<textarea>'
'.$data.'
'</textarea>'
..
```

The problem is:
if contain the `</textarea>` tag in data, my codes truncted by the tag. Because `</textarea>` is end tag of textarea  values. Any solve there to not execute `</textarea>` tag(which contained $data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning up `$data` before outputting it, such as:

`'.htmlentities($data).'`

Also, take a look at the available flags for the function in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: Is it <textarea>'.htmlentities($data).'</textarea> 
?

Comment: It should work, give it a try.