# How should I echo a PHP string variable that contains special characters?

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I'm trying to populate a form with some data that contains special characters (e.g. single quote, double quote,<,>,?,","".~,,!@#$%^&*()_+}{":?<<>,./;'[.] etc) :

```
<input type="text" name="message" size="200" maxlength="200"
 value =<?php echo $message;?>>
```

However, `$message`, which comes from a MySQL table, isn't displayed correctly - any HTML output that should be in `$message` is broken.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly escape html form input default values in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will prevent your tags from being broken by the echo:

`<?php echo htmlentities($message); ?>`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to display it

```
echo htmlspecialchars($messge, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

That's what I usually do.

Since the answers are difference:

[htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars) is worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use the following code, see [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($videoId, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

whats wrong with using a constant ?

```
<?php
define(foo,'<,>,?,","".~,,!@#$%^&*()_+}{":?<<>,./;');
$foo2="'[.]";
echo constant('foo').$foo2;
?>
```

you need to put the '[.]' into a variable, as a constant will break on a **'** (single quote).