# how do you echo the following special characters using PHP and make the browser display these:

Tags: php

Help I am stuck  with the following Problem and i cant figure this out. I am supposed to do the following in PHP:

Set a variable to the following: “<&¢£¥€©>” and output it as shown to 
the browser window.

Here is my code:
`<?php`
`$str = "&lt;&amp;&cent;&pound;&yen;&euro;&copy;&gt;"`
`echo htmlspecialchars($str);`
`?>`

but i keep getting an error.

Comment: Why do you need to use htmlspecialchars when you already encode to HTML character already?

Comment: Read from here (multiple solution available) :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150403/how-should-i-echo-a-php-string-variable-that-contains-special-characters

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon

```
$str = "&lt;&amp;&cent;&pound;&yen;&euro;&copy;&gt;"; // <-- missing semicolon
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

Comment: Yes thank u all for your help, I was trying to print out those characters u mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to do something like this?

```
$str = "<&¢£¥€©>";
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```