# how to extract data from mysql that contains special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

Example data in my database:

`blabla<blabla`

I use phpmyadmin and can see that the data has been input successfully.

However when I try to display the data what I get is:

`blabla` NOT `blabla<blabla`

In other words, everything after the `<` symbol does not display.

```
 <?
   while ($mouselist_row = mysql_fetch_array($mouselist)) {
   $mouselist_commonstrain = mysql_real_escape_string($mouselist_row['Common_Strain']);

    echo "$mouselist_commonstrain.";
}
   ?>
```

I tried using  `mysql_real_escape_string`.
Is there something in particular needed to display the `<`?
thanks

Comment: If part of a HTML page output, you need HTML escaping; else the browser will likely misinterpret it as tag.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: This issue is not really related to MySQL. You can demonstrate the same behavior by just echoing a string. HTML tags begin with an angle bracket (`<`). To display an angle bracket, you need to echo `blabla&lt;blabla`. Use a built in function to scan your string, and replace the "special characters" in HTML with markup to display the desired characters.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($mouselist_commonstrain);
```

(It needs to be HTML escaped.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$mouselist_commonstrain = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($mouselist_row['Common_Strain']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't escaping SQL but HTML. As answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php) you can use `htmlspecialchars` function.