# Why doesn't htmlspecialchars convert quotes inside an input value?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="nr_p_vac" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['nr_p_vac']); ?>">
```

where `$row['nr_p_vac']` is test `' " / /n /t <>`.

When I'm not using `htmlspecialchars` in the input there's only `test '` (of course, because `"` is not escaped).

When I'm using the `htmlspecialchars` function the input has the correct value `' " / /n /t <>` (because now `'` and `"` are properly escaped).

**But shouldn't the content of the input be transformed into something like `test &apos; '&quot;'` etc.?**

*Is it ok to use htmlspecialchars in this case?*

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have read the manual, that's the reson I asked the question. The manual says:  The translations performed are:

    '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
    '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
    "'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
    '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
    '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The problem is, inside my value=" ", it doesn't change the characters like the manual says. I wanted to know why is this happening.

Comment: Try echo htmlspecialchars("ab\"cd"); Output :`ab&quot;cd`

Comment: _“The problem is, inside my value=" ", it doesn't change the characters like the manual says”_ – did you look at the generated HTML output (view source code in your browser) – or just at what your browser displays when it has _interpreted_ it as HTML already …?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I forgot to check the source. I understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look the page source and you will see that the value is

```
' &quot; / /n /t &lt;&gt;
```

It is ok to use it in your case

Already answered here:
[How to properly escape html form input default values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

Comment: Oh, I understand now. By the way, given the fact the question is already answered somewhere else should I delete my question?