# LIKE statement passes wrong character in excel

Tags: php, excel

My idea is a search query then after click an image button it will redirect to the query to excel code

here is my code for the image button

```
$expQuery = SELECT * FROM reginformation WHERE name LIKE '%da%' AND deleted = 0; //This is an example query
<a id="exportbutton" style="margin-left:5px;" href="regListToExcel.php?query=<?php echo $expQuery ?> " ><img src="images/export_to_excel.png" style="margin-left:0px; width:5%" title='Download List'></a>
```

The code to the regListToExcel.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/excel');                                  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="EventRegistrationLogs('.date("Y-m-d").').xls"');
?>
<html>
<table border=2>
<tr>
<th>Registration ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th><th>Birthdate</th><th>Address</th>
<th>Email Address</th><th>Employment Status</th><th>Contact No.</th><th>Facebook</th>
<th>Twitter</th><th>Instagram</th><th>Event</th>
<th>Where did you hear about this event?</th><th>Photo Link</th><th>Province</th><th>Friend's Name</th>
<th>Friend's Email Address</th><th>Friend's Name</th>
<th>Friend's Email Address</th><th>Date Registered</th>
</tr>
<?php
include("dbcon.php");
$query=$_GET['query'];
echo "$query";
$export = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$bgcolor = "F6F7EA";

            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($export))

                {   

                    if ($bgcolor == "ECEFD7")
                        { 
                        $bgcolor = "F6F7EA"; 
                        }
                    else 
                        { 
                        $bgcolor = "ECEFD7"; 
                        }
                    if($data['province'] == "")
                        {           
                        $province = "";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        $query = "SELECT province FROM province WHERE provid = $data[province]";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    $province = $row['province'];
                    }
            ?>   
                    <tr><td width="1000px" style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['regID']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['name']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['gender']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['age']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['bdate']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['address']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['emailadd']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['employmentstatus']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['contactno']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['facebook']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['twitter']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['instagram']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['event']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['wherehearevent']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['photolink']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $province?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['referfriend1']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['referemail1']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['referfriend2']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['referemail2']?></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#<?echo $bgcolor;?>;>"><?php echo $data['date_register']?></td>
                    </tr>
<?php   } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The query it gives to the excel is 
**SELECT * FROM reginformation WHERE name LIKE 'Ú%' AND deleted = 0**
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental issues with this example is that the query is not escaped before being passed through to the subsequent page.

In particular, it's worth using PHP's "htmlentities" function on $expQuery, and then validating what's being passed through the request. A browser tool like Firebug can help you with this.

Additionally, your code is subject to arbitrary SQL injection attacks. You should be using mysqli_escape_string on your query (and, ideally, only passing through the parts that are actually dynamic).

Comment: What do you mean about the query not being escaped and the use of htmlentities? Could you give me a sample to understand it clearer?

Comment: Take a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php

In particular, you just want to make sure your query comes through correctly on the other side. You can simply do a:

    print_r($query);die:

To make sure the value is correct.

Regarding SQL injection, just think about what would happen if someone posted a request to regListToExcel.php with a query like:

    DROP TABLE reginformation;

Comment: When I tried htmlspecialcharacters it gave me this query **SELECT * FROM reginformation WHERE name LIKE 'ڥ' AND deleted = 0** which should be **SELECT * FROM reginformation WHERE name LIKE '%da%' AND deleted = 0**