# Explode function in php , how to keep data in text box after using explode?

Tags: php, explode

I am using explode function to explode the texts in two parts, and what i want is that after explode i want to keep the exploded part in text box, its working fine but for some situation its not working. Here is the code. I want {\"EVERYONE"} in text box but its only coming as { in textbox. Please help

```
<?php
 $str   = "HELLO   {\"EVERYONE\"}";
 $split=explode(' ', $str, 2);
 print_r($split);
 echo '<input type="text" style="width:300px;" value="'.$split[1].'">';
?>
```

Comment: Always check source code in your browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add htmlentities around the value:

```
<?php
 $str   = "HELLO   {\"EVERYONE\"}"; // double quote, \ is handled as escape sign
 $str   = 'HELLO   {\"EVERYONE\"}'; //single quote, \ is handled as string
 $str   = "HELLO   {\\\"EVERYONE\\\"}"; //escape the escape sign
 $split=explode(' ', $str, 2);
 print_r($split);
 echo '<input type="text" style="width:300px;" value="'.htmlentities($split[1]).'">';
?>
```

More info about htmlentities can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Thanks, Its working but \ is still not coming in textbox

Comment: yes right, its escaped charecter, what you told to see edit?? where?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use htmlspecialchars to properly escape html default values.

@see [How to properly escape html form input default values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

Comment: So in your case, `echo '<input type="text" style="width:300px;" value="'.htmlspecialchars($split[1]).'">';` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your input line with

```
 echo '<input type="text" style="width:300px;" value="' . htmlspecialchars($split[1]) . '">';
```

special symbols like ¡™£¢∞§¶ get turned into little black diamonds with question marks in them because htmlentities doesn't know how to handle them, but htmlspecialchars does.

Comment: No. that's because of the charset.

Comment: Ahh, okay so, passing third argument as UTF-8(if its not the default one), it works for both the cases.

Comment: Thanks, it working now but I want {\"EVERYONE\"} in text box now its coming {"EVERYONE"} , \    not coming, why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
htmlentities($split[1])
```

this will resolve your problem.