# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in a html select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the  following java script :

```
 var i = 2;
            $(".addmore").on('click', function () {
                count = $('table tr').length;
                var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum" + i + "'>" + count + ".</span></td>";
                data += "\n\\n\
            <td><select><?php foreach($commodity_name as $value){?><option><?php echo $value['commodity_name']; ?></option><?php }?></select></td>\n\
             <td><input type='text' id='commodity_type" + i + "' name='commodity_type[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='unit_per_pack" + i + "' name='unit_per_pack[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='no_of_units" + i + "' name='no_of_units[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='total_quantity" + i + "' name='total_quantity[]'/></td></tr>";
                $('table').append(data);
                i++;
            });
```

Which is supposed to populate and auto generate a dropdown, but I keep getting the  folloing error :

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

...on>CREPE BANDAGE 2" DOZENSCREPE BANDAGES 4"          DOZ

Which I believe is due to the use of either the  following characters ' or " in the database data. Is there a way I can bypass the  characters ?

Comment: When writing to HTML *always* escape the output (except in rare cases where the *raw* text is required). Sadly, PHP has always made this stupidly cumbersome and non idiomatic: many template frameworks fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly escape html form input default values in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249151/how-to-properly-escape-html-form-input-default-values-in-php)

Comment: Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before sending your data through the ajax call

Comment: escape those characters?

Comment: (Note that `htmlspecialchars` is done *when writing to HTML* and does not affect the proper use of parameterized SQL statements when saving to the database.)

Comment: If he had use `htmlspecialchars` before saving data to the database, then there wouldn't have been a need to do anything for displaying it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that , assigning string in variable , you should not use a blank new line while coding in JS , On the otherhand if you want to add new line of html ,use br .

Something used as following

```
var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum" + i + "'>" + count + ".</span></td>";
data += "<td><select><?php foreach($commodity_name as $value){?><option><?php echo $value['commodity_name']; ?></option><?php }?></select></td>";
data += "<td><input type='text' id='commodity_type" + i + "' name='commodity_type[]'/></td>";
data += "<td><input type='text' id='unit_per_pack" + i + "' name='unit_per_pack[]'/></td>";
data += "<td><input type='text' id='no_of_units" + i + "' name='no_of_units[]'/></td>";
data += "<td><input type='text' id='total_quantity" + i + "' name='total_quantity[]'/></td></tr>";
```