# HTML form posting default values

Tags: html

I have a HTML form in which for some fields the user will enter the values and for some some fields i want to pass some default values, is there a way to do it?

Comment: There are several ways of doing that, but to implement them first you should learn HTML and Javascript. This is no place to start learning from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with PHP here is another thread with the answer:
[HTML/PHP - default input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017598/html-php-default-input-value)